# Android Disable Intent PDF Viewer Menu Bar within App

Tags: java, android, pdf

Currently I have the PDF viewer working through the intent and a local file I want to display from the following code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way to disable to top menu bar when rendering the PDF through the intent (see picture below)?

[image: top bar]